# Undefined references with using autotools

Tags: c++, gcc, autotools

I am having a struggle these days solving these **undefined references** which I described below by using autotools on my machine.

I am not sure what is the reason why I have undefined refs, but I doubt there is something related to autotools, maybe c++17 is not fully integrated with autotools, my setup is bad or... I am out of ideas.

I checked the syntax trillion times, moving template definition to header only, changing parameter count to the functions, rearranged Makefiles.. etc.. still nothing.

Maybe you could help me?

---

configure.ac

```
AC_INIT([CRYPTO], [0.1], [iamhidingmymail@gmail.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE 

AC_PROG_RANLIB
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG(C++)
AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-std=c++17], [
                        CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -std=c++17"])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([ fsio/Makefile logger/Makefile  rsa/Makefile primes/Makefile Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

topdir ->Makefile.am

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
SUBDIRS = logger fsio  primes rsa 

AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) -Wall -std=c++17

bin_PROGRAMS = crypto.out

crypto_out_SOURCES = bigInt.cpp  Source.cpp  

crypto_out_LDADD = -lpthread fsio/libFsio.a logger/libLogger.a rsa/libRSA.a primes/libPrimes.a
```

fsio/Makefile.am

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libFsio.a

libFsio_a_SOURCES = fsio.cpp

libFsio_a_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) -Wall -std=c++17
```

Logger/Makefile.am

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libLogger.a

libLogger_a_SOURCES = loga.cpp

libLogger_a_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir) -Wall -std=c++17
```

---

undefined reference 1:

```
Source.cpp:17: undefined reference to `void logger::loga::I<char const*, char const*, char const*>(char const*, char const*, char const*)'
```

while Source.cpp:17 is:

```
logger::loga l("testlog.log");
    l.I("Test", "test ","!");//line 17
```

and defined as:

```
template<typename ...message>
    void loga::I(message ...m){
        //(this is fold expression)
        //code
    }
```

---

undefined reference 2:

```
logger/libLogger.a(libLogger_a-loga.o): In function `logger::loga::loga(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
<path>/logger/loga.cpp:7: undefined reference to `fsio::file::file(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, std::_Ios_Openmode)'
<path>/logger/loga.cpp:7: undefined reference to `fsio::file::operator=(fsio::file const&)'
```

while loga.cpp:7 is:

```
loga::loga(std::string filename){
        Logger = std::move(fsio::file(filename));//line 7
    }
```

and **Logger** is defined as:

```
::fsio::file Logger;
```

in the fsio.h

---

however definitions of **file** constructor and operator= can be found below

```
//in header file constructor is declared as
(std::string& filename, std::fstream::openmode it = 
    (std::ios::app|std::ios::out|std::ios::in));

file::file(std::string& filename , std::ios_base::openmode om ){
        //code
        //code
    }

file& file::operator=(const file& f){
        //code
        return *this;
    }
```

---

binary is compiled with:

```
g++  -g -O2 -std=c++17   -o crypto.out bigInt.o Source.o -lpthread fsio/libFsio.a logger/libLogger.a rsa/libRSA.a primes/libPrimes.a
```

---

I made custom script for running configure, make, etc.. and it is:

./build

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

aclocal
autoconf
automake --add-missing
./configure
echo
make -j4

echo "building done, running application:"
./crypto.out
echo "done!"
```

FYI

```
 Ubuntu 17.10

    uname -a

    Linux nikola 4.13.0-041300-generic #201709031731 SMP Sun Sep 3 21:33:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    automake --version

    automake (GNU automake) 1.15

    g++ -v

    gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)
```

---

If you feel code is short please visit my github

https://github.com/NikolaLozanovski/crypto/tree/logger

branch: logger

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For **UR1** I did **define** the template functions inside the **header** file, previously template functions were declared in header but defined in source. That do the trick

For **UR2** I **included** the static library where those functions were defined, with using _**LIBADD** directive in the respective **makefile**. The compiler didn't knew where to find those symbols for the functions. Now it knows :)